# Save objects to database from array

Tags: php, arrays, save

I'm trying to save several objects from predefined data. It saves only first set of data or if I change code it saves data as "array".
Here is the code:

```
<?php

$category = array(
    'Account/Profile',
    'Blogs',
);

$question = array(
    'How do I change my email notifications',
    'How do I edit my profile details',
    'What is a blog?',
);

$answer = array(
    '<p>To change your email notifications</p>',
    '<p>To change your profile details</p>',
    '<p>A weblog, or blog, is.</p>',
);


$questionCount = count($question);
for ($i = 0; $i <= $questionCount; $i++) {
    $faq           = new Object();
    $faq->category = $category[$i];
    $faq->question = $question[$i];
    $faq->answer   = $answer[$i];
}

$didSave = $faq->save();
```

How can I pull data from arrays and create multiple objects using that data?

Comment: what do you want to do with the data?

Comment: It's already an array, there is no need to convert it. Beside the question is not clear, try better

Comment: I really dont understand why youre assigning data to an array, then assigning that array to another array, and then again, for a 3rd time, assigning that array to another variable....whats the point?

Comment: I don't know either why I was assigning array to another array lol, I was trying different options from other similar files so I left that in the code. I'll try to revise the code and post more.

Comment: Ok Thanks to KyleK after few minutes of messing with it it works now. If question belongs to same category I repeat that category in categories array. Now saves all categories and q/a. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go....

```
 $cats = array('Account/Profile', 'Blogs');

 $question = array(
  'How do I change my email notifications', 
  'What is a blog?',);

 $answer = array(
  '<p>To change your email notifications you can do so from notifications page</p>', 
  '<p>A weblog, or blog, is arguably one of the fundamental DNA pieces of most types of social networking site.</p>',);

//Then count the questions and iterate
 for($i=0;$i<=count($question);$i++)
  {
   $object = New Object; //Your object class
   //NEW OBJECT TO SAVE, I call it object, but you have to fill this in,
   //with whatever class/object it is youre creating, and saving
   $object->category = $cats[$i];
   $object->question = $question[$i];
   $object->answer = $answer[$i];
   $object->save();
  }
```

**NEW EDIT BASED ON YOUR REPOST**

```
 for($i=0;$i<=count($question);$i++)
 {
 $faq = new ElggObject();
 $faq->subtype = 'faq';
    $faq->container_guid = $CONFIG->site_guid;
    $faq->owner_guid = $CONFIG->site_guid;
 $faq->category = $cats[$i];
 $faq->question = $question[$i];
 $faq->answer = $answer[$i];
 $faq->access_id = $access;
 if($faq->save()) {
        system_message(elgg_echo("faq:add:success"));
    } else {
        register_error(elgg_echo("faq:add:error:save"));
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to check which array has the highest length first, otherwise it won't work in case array have variable length

Comment: That is true, but in the case that some categories have multiple questions, then this breaks anyways, regardless.....it more comes down to how he is handling his data, the way it is now, is not optimal....so lets say the blog category had 2 questions and I counted $questions being the highest, the algorithm still has no idea which questions belong to which category.  Thats up to the OP to change the way his data is retrieved/display/organized...not up to me :)  He should be doing some sort of key=>value type structure

Comment: Thanks for such quick response guys. Yeah I did not account yet for one category having more than one question/answer. I'll try to post more of the code and explain more. It is basically saving predefined categories in FAQ and categories have questions and answers, I wanted to create these categories and assign questions/answers to them.

Comment: This code saves only second set of values in 3 arrays (cat, question, answer) so it only saves Blog (category), What is blog? (question) and second answer.

Comment: The reason that is occuring is because you didnt provide us full knowledge of what $object is....If you want a new object everytime, you have to instantiate one.....look at my new edit.....the way I originally had it wasn't working because it was basically saving twice to the same object, so the first entry was merely overwritten.....you have to call a NEW object for each entry.....SEE NEW EDIT

Comment: Kyle, I edited original question with your code suggestion. It does not save anything with it. Please take a look.

Comment: Well for one, you're not closing the loop, and two, I see no $faq->save() being called

Comment: I'm sorry, I should mention this is the action file, called by the form so save is done when action is called. I edited original again, posted full code changed according to your suggestion. I also added extra question and answer but still only have 2 categories. Am I better off just using one category and than saving multiple q/a via your code with $i++ to just that one category? thanks.

Comment: yeah you can't do that, because you have to save each one as you loop....so the save needs to be inside the loop

Comment: I tried your last edit and still does not save anything :( am I better off just specifying one category and than use your sample code to save all question/answer arrays? Than I can have similar code for other categories. I was trying to get all categories and q/a saved in one click but from your earlier comments if some categories have more questions than others than it will be a mess.

Comment: Ok Thanks to KyleK after few minutes of messing with it it works now. If question belongs to same category I repeat that category in categories array. Now saves all categories and q/a. Thanks.